# Error using __declspec(dllexport) : Unknown type name '__declspec'

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, dllexport

I am trying to export a function to shared object (`.so`) using NDK from c++ using terminal on macOS mojave . I have installed latest versions of command line tool and Xcode.

*Here's my `GetNumber()` which i want to export*

```
#include <iostream>
#define DllExport __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" {
   DllExport int GetNumber() {
      return 5 ;
   }
}
```

*After compiling the code using NDK , it throws the following error* ,

[image]

I tried out clang and Xcode compiler as well as on tried same patterns on Windows and Ubuntu . I get the same error .

[Tutorial i followed to export shared library using ndk](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-an-android-command-line-application-using-the-ndk-build-tools)

Comment: Isn't `__declspec` a Visual C++ specific extension for helping creating DLLs?

Comment: `__declspec` is microsoft compiler specific, and the Android ndk probably uses `clang`.'

Comment: And on POSIX platforms (like Linux or macOS, and since Android uses Linux then that to) it's not needed anyway. All non-static symbols are by default exported.

Comment: `clang` supports the keyword when specifying `-fms-extensions`.

Comment: Yah i got the flag recommendation "-fms-extensions" while compiling in Xcode . But still Xcode throws error for dllexport attribute not found

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The command Line tool in mac has the macro saved in __config file of c++ libraries.

Comment: If your build needs to support multiple platforms, I highly recommend not using `__declspec` at all (even in the Windows builds).  Having preprocessor macros in a header trying to figure out whether your build is DLL or LIB, Windows or not, the DLL being built, or a DLL trying to use the header , is an enormous pain in the ass.  It seems convenient at first, but it really truly isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `JNIEXPORT` instead of `DllExport` on Android platforms.

The referenced tutorial you provided in your question is too old for current Android NDK development.

Comment: I tried same code code on Ubuntu to compile using gcc throws same .

Comment: You should use build tool chains shipped with Android NDK rather than the PC built-in compiler.

Comment: Here (https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample) is my personal NDK project for your reference just in case it may be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the example !

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you want to use declspec on cross-platform builds, what you'll have is something loosely like this, given a project `ABC`:

Windows project doing the exporting declares like so during dll builds:

```
#define ABC_EXPORT
```

All non-Windows projects or projects that plan on interacting with a lib version of the project (and the lib version of the project itself) declare:

```
#define ABC_LIB
```

then you have in your project:

```
#ifdef ABC_LIB //or #if (defined(ABC_LIB) || !defined(WIN32))
  #define ABC_API
#else
  #ifdef ABC_EXPORT 
    #define ABC_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define ABC_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif
#endif
```

Then all your functions are declared like:

```
ABC_API void foo();
```

Better yet, if you have an OS obstraction layer you can use another `#define` instead of `__declspec` to completely insure that POSIX builds never have to worry about this stuff.

I highly recommend using export files instead, because this is not fun.